# I need a regular expression for javascript which searches the . (dot) in the string followed by 2 digit

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression for javascript which searches the `.` (dot) in the string followed by 2 digit

Input string is:

```
4.306.000.438.47;286.02;23.232.344.00
```

Output string should be:

```
4.306.000.438,47;286,02;23.232.344,00
```

The output string is actually a Turkish currency separated by ";" and I want the "," to be placed before 2 digits of the number. Please help me with a regular expression.

Comment: which language u use java or javascript?

Comment: I use javascript and I want the regular expression fo javascript

Comment: @GolamMazid Sajib he uses JS. OP: you might want to use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: @AlexisPhilip at first he tag java and javascript.... but why close with more focus

Comment: @DheerajGore try with this regex: `(?:\d+).(?:\d{2})`... then replace with `,`

Comment: Yes I'm going to use replace finally however before that I need to search the string which has .[0-9] at the end every number which are separated by ;

Comment: I'm getting an error unexpected token ?. In the console.
here the code which I'm running in the console.

var string1 = "4306000438.47,286.02"; 
  var string2 = string1.replace(',',';');
console.log(string2);
  var string3 = string2.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g,'.');
console.log(string3);
var string4= string3.replace((?:\d+).(?:\d{2}),',');
console.log(string4);

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/WOjyKE/1) what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex: `/\.(?=\d\d(?:;|$))/g`

```js
console.log('4.306.000.438.47;286.02;23.232.344.00'.replace(/\.(?=\d\d(?:;|$))/g, ','));
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/WOjyKE/1)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

Capture group, optional `(\d+\.)*` prefix, literal `\.` needs to be escaped and prefixed with a digit and followed by exactly 2 digits ending in a `\b` word boundary. `//g` makes the regex replace global.

```
input  = "4.306.000.438.47;286.02;23.232.344.00"
output = input.replace(/((\d+\.)*\d+)\.(\d{2})\b/g,'$1,$3')
// "4.306.000.438,47;286,02;23.232.344,00"
```